# How can i do re coding without assign null value?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

How can i do below without assign null value "Tex=null"?

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo("C:/temp/Arungg.txt");
            StreamWriter Tex;
            Tex = null;
            if (!f.Exists)
            {
                f.CreateText();
            }
            else
            {
                Tex = f.AppendText();
            }
                Tex.WriteLine("Test1");
                Tex.WriteLine("Test2");
                Tex.Write(Tex.NewLine);
                Tex.Close();
                Console.WriteLine(" The Text file named Arungg is created ");


        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileInfo f = new FileInfo("C:/temp/Arungg.txt");

        StreamWriter Tex = f.Exists ? f.AppendText() : f.CreateText();

        Tex.WriteLine("Test1");
        Tex.WriteLine("Test2");
        Tex.Write(Tex.NewLine);
        Tex.Close();

        Console.WriteLine(" The Text file named Arungg is created ");
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure that `Tex` is assigned in every code path.

```
        if (!f.Exists)
        {
            Tex = f.CreateText();
        }
```

Note that the `AppendText` method will create the file if it doesn't exist.
Therefore, you don't need the `if` statement at all.

Answer (score 2):

Replace what you have with something like this.

```
using (StreamWriter Tex = new StreamWriter("C:/temp/Arungg.txt", true, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    Tex.WriteLine("Test1");
    Tex.WriteLine("Test2");
    Tex.Write(Tex.NewLine);
    Console.WriteLine(" The Text file named Arungg is created ");
}
```

This will create the file if it does not exist or open it for appending if it does. No `if` necessary, no code that won't compile (as in your sample), and you get proper disposal of resources.

Answer (score 1):

```
Tex = f.Exists? f.AppendText(): f.CreateText();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If f.Exists is false, Tex never gets set before it's used after the if-block, so you have to assign it something.

I'm also pretty sure you'll get a NullReferenceException in that case as well, so are you sure you're not just meaning to assign Tex in your if-block?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I always truncated the file :)

```
        var f = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\Arungg.txt");
        var writer = f.Exists ? f.AppendText() : new StreamWriter(f.OpenWrite());
        using (writer)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Test1");
            writer.WriteLine("Test2");
            writer.WriteLine(); // No need for NewLine
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps, but your use of `writer.WriteLine();` was itself an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't instantiate your StreamWriter, it's going to bomb on you.  You need to assign a value to get it to compile, but without an instance, it's not going to do what you think it will do.

Perhaps simplify and [consider using File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx)?